# NestJS GET route returns data wrapped in data field

Tags: typescript, rest, nestjs, crud

If have the following route which should return the username and city of a user.

Controller:

```
  @HttpCode(200)
  @Get(':userId')
  async getUserUnauthenticated(@Param("userId") userId: string): Promise<GetUserDto> {
    return this.usersService.getUsers(userId, false)
  }
```

Service:

```
async getUsers(userId: string, authenticated: boolean): Promise<GetUserDto> {
    const user = await this.fusionAuthService.searchUserById(userId);
    const impacter = await this.impactersService.retrieveImpacterFromDatabaseById(userId)
    if (authenticated) {
      return {
        username: user.username,
        city: impacter.address.city,
        image: user.imageUrl
      }
    } else {
      return {
        username: user.username,
        city: impacter.address.city
      }
    }
  }
```

DTO:

```
export class GetUserDto {
    username: string;
    city: string;
    image?: string;
}
```

But instead of

```
{
    "username": "ExampleName",
    "city": "ExampleTown"
}
```

it returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "username": "ExampleName",
    "city": "ExampleTown"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have some interceptor that transform your output, take a look here how it works, https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors maybe you will be able to figure out in your project how it's.

Regards.

Comment: thanks you! in the main.ts a global Interceptor was set. **app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ResponseDataFormatterInterceptor());** This Interceptor added the data {} wrapper.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad that I was able to help you!